# Unable to set tmux window title to current program

Tags: tmux

I am pretty new to tmux and have been using it for now a week or so. I want the tmux window titles to be set to the current program i am running like vim/htop etc and not to the host i am connected to.

Below is my config and as per tmux man page `#W` is used for that however it does not seem to work in my case and my window titles are always being set as `fqdn[username]`

```
set -g status on
set -g status-interval 1
set -g status-fg colour231
set -g status-bg colour234
set -g status-left-length 20



set -g status-left '#{?client_prefix,#[fg=colour254]#[bg=colour31]#[bold],#[fg=colour16]#[bg=colour254]#[bold]} #S #{?client_prefix,#[fg=colour31]#[bg=colour234]#[nobold],#[fg=colour254]#[bg=colour234]#[nobold]}'


set -g window-status-format "#[fg=colour244,bg=colour234]#I #[fg=colour240] #[default]#W "
set -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour234,bg=colour31]#[fg=colour117,bg=colour31] #I  #[fg=colour231,nobold]#W #[fg=colour31,bg=colour234,nobold]"
set -g window-status-last-style fg=colour31
set-window-option -g window-status-fg colour249

set -g status-right-length 150
set -g status-right  "#[fg=colour225,bg=colour234]#[fg=colour234,bg=colour225] #(date +%a' '%b' '%d) %H:%M#[fg=colour234]#[bg=colour234]#{?pane_synchronized,#[bg=colour236]#[fg=colour160]#[fg=colour255]#[bg=colour160] PANES-ARE-SYNCED !! #[fg=colour234]#[bg=colour=234],#[fg=colour22]#[fg=colour255]#[bg=colour22] PANES-NOT-SYNCED #[fg=colour234]#[bg=colour234]}#[fg=colour255,bg=colour234]#[fg=colour234,bg=colour255,bold]#h"
```

So can anyone please let me know how do i do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that on some machines I would get a `username@hostname:~` and on others I would get the name of the executable. On both machines `tmux show -gw` showed:

```
automatic-rename on
automatic-rename-format "#{?pane_in_mode,[tmux],#{pane_current_command}}#{?pane_dead,[dead],}"
```

So I wondered what was happening... it turns out that the option `allow-rename` was `on` where I could see `username@hostname:~` and `off` where I saw the current executable name.

`allow-rename` makes it possible for your shell (in my case bash) to change the pane title with an escape sequence and in some configurations (for example if your `TERM` environment variable starts with `screen`) the title will be updated every time your prompt is shown (this is more of a shell related issue so if you are interested please look for information on `PS1` and in `/etc/bash/bashrc`). To see the effect try this:

```
echo -en '\033kTMUXISCOOL\033]' ; sleep 5
```

When you run that command in `tmux` you should see the current pane title change to `TMUXISCOOL` for 5 seconds then back to `username@hostname:~`. By putting the following line into `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g allow-rename off
```

The pane title should display the current executable... or whatever is in `automatic-rename-format`.